# Creating Responsive tabular layout

Tags: html, css

What would be the most efficient way of accomplishing the following task:

When page loads in 1920 x 1024 the page displays a full page of images all evenly spaced 324 px wide each like this:

```
[]  []  []
[]  []  []
[]  []  []
[]  []  []
```

Now when I resize the browser I want to change this and have the images 2 by 2's and eventually by 1's as  this:

```
  [] []
  [] []
  [] []
  [] []
```

Then by 1's

```
   []
   []
   []
   []
```

I will have pagination to flip to the next page, but I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to accomplish this that will be crossbrowser compatible.

My idea is to have have divs for each image and then assign 3 classes to each div, along the lines of 1, 2 and 3.

Then as the browser resizes, have a JS function appoint appropriate class to each element.

Option 2 (which I feel is slightly better):

Float all the divs to the left and use media queries to set their widths.

Is the are more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

Media queries would be your best bet.  You could surround your images with a container div, then in each media query for the given `min-width` screen size, set the width of your container div.  The images just need a `float: left;` css applied and they'll flow within the container div.

You could even take it a step further if you want to force the number of columns in each screen width and maximize the space used.  Wrap each image itself in a wrapper div, then in your largest screen size media query, set the width of that wrapper div to 33% to get 3 columns.  In the two column scenario, set the width to 50%, and finally in the single column scenario, set the width to 100%.  Then apply the `float: left;` to the wrapper div of the individual images.

Answer (score 0):

This might be quite helpful - http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table

Only hunch is that you would have to implement Bootstrap Framework -